# add ingredient to shopping List

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

[image]
I have a project to add an ingredient in a recipe to "Shopping List".
And in this picture there are several ingredients at the bottom "sugar".
When I click on the plus sign I want to add the ingredient to the "shopping List".
How can I solve this problem?

In this file, you create an ingredient with this ingredient's data such as its name and quantity.
CreateIngredient:

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-container>
            <v-layout row>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                    <h2 class="btn-style">Add Ingredient</h2>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout row>
                <v-flex xs12>
                    <form @submit.prevent="onAddIngredient">
                        <v-layout>
                            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                                <v-text-field name="id" label="Id" id="id" v-model="id" color="#43A047" required>
                                </v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                        <v-layout>
                            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                                <v-text-field name="name" label="Name" id="name" v-model="Name" color="#43A047" required>
                                </v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                        <v-layout>
                            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                                <v-text-field name="ingredientsQuantity" label="Ingredients Quantity" id="ingredientsQuantity" v-model="Quantity" color="#43A047" multi-line required>
                                </v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                        <v-layout row>
                            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                                <v-btn class="green darken-1 color" type="submit">
                                    Add
                                </v-btn>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </form>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
                return {
                    id: "",
                    Name: "",
                    Quantity: "",
                };
            },
            computed: {
                formIsValid() {
                    return (
                        this.id !== "" &&
                        this.Name !== "" &&
                        this.Quantity !== ""
                    );
                }
            },
            methods: {
                onAddIngredient() {
                    if (!this.formIsValid) {
                        return;
                    }
                    const ingredientData = {
                        id: this.id,
                        Name: this.Name,
                        Quantity: this.Quantity
                    };
                    this.$store.commit("createIngredients", ingredientData);
                    const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(ingredientData);
                    // console.log("S: ", stringifiedData);
                    localStorage.setItem("ingredient", stringifiedData);
                    console.log("We got : ", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ingredient")));
                }
            },
    };
</script>
<style scoped>
    .btn-style {
        color: #43a047;
    }
    
    .color {
        color: #fafafa;
    }
</style>
```

And this file that displays all the ingredients
shoppingList:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <v-container class="mb-30">
            <v-flex class="floating-right">
                <v-btn large router to="/CreateNewIngrediets" class="green darken-1  btn-style margine mr-50">
                    <v-icon class="green darken-1 btn-style">mdi-plus</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </v-flex>
            <v-container>
                <v-layout row wrap v-for="ingredient in ingredients" :key="ingredient.id" class="mb-3 mt-4">
                    <v-flex xs6 sm8 md4 offset-sm1 offset-md2>
                        <v-card class="grey lighten-4 pl-3 ">
                            <v-container fluid>
                                <v-layout row class="pl-14">
                                    <v-flex xs7 sm8 md9>
                                        <v-card-title primary-title>
                                            <v-flex xs7 sm8 md9>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ ingredient.Name }}
                                                </div>
                                            </v-flex>
                                            <v-flex xs7 sm8 md9>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ ingredient.Quantity }}
                                                </div>
                                            </v-flex>
                                            <v-flex xs5 sm4 md2>
                                                <v-btn class="deleteColorIcon">
                                                    <v-icon left class=" pl-4" @click="
                                    $store.commit('delete_ingredient', ingredient.id)
                                  ">
                                                        mdi-delete
                                                    </v-icon>
                                                    <!-- </v-btn> -->
                                                </v-btn>
                                            </v-flex>
                                        </v-card-title>
                                    </v-flex>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-container>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-container>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            Recipes() {
                    return this.$store.getters.loadedRecipes;
                },
                ingredients() {
                    return this.$store.getters.loadedingredients;
                }
        }
    };
</script>
<style scoped>
    .color {
        color: #43a047;
    }
    
    .deleteColorIcon {
        color: #e53935;
    }
    
    .btn-style {
        color: aliceblue;
    }
</style>
```

And this file that displays the recipe as the image above, and through it, all the recipe elements, including the ingredients, are displayed.
Recipe:

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex x12>
                <v-card>
                    <!-- <v-card-title> -->
                    <v-card-text>
                        <h4 class="btn-style mt-4 mb-4 font">
                  {{ recipe.title }}
                </h4>
                        <v-img height="530px" :src="recipe.imageUrl" class="mb-4"></v-img>
                        <div class="btn-style mb-6">
                            {{ recipe.description }}
                        </div>
                        <div v-for="ing in recipe.ingredients" :key="ing.id">
                            {{ ing.Name }} {{ ing.Quantity }}
                            <v-btn class="green darken-1  color mb-5 ml-4 mr-4 pl-50">
                                <v-icon class="green darken-1 btn-style">mdi-plus</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </div>
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <!-- <v-flex xs5 sm4 md2> -->
                        <v-btn class=" mb-4 mr-4">
                            <v-icon left class=" pl-4 ">
                                mdi-pen
                            </v-icon>
                            <!-- </v-btn> -->
                        </v-btn>
                        <!-- </v-flex> -->
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
    import {
        mapGetters
    }
    from "vuex";
    export default {
        props: ["id"],
        computed: {
            recipe() {
                    const loadedRecipe = this.$store.getters.loadedRecipe(this.id);
                    console.log("We loaded a recipe with value : ", loadedRecipe);
                    return loadedRecipe;
                },
                ingredient() {
                    return this.$store.getters.loadedingredient(this.id);
                }
        },
        methods: {

        }
    };
</script>
<style scoped>
    .btn-style {
        color: #43a047;
    }
    
    .color {
        color: #fafafa;
    }
    
    .deleteColorIcon {
        color: #e53935;
    }
    
    .font {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a on click observer un your button, define a function that would execute in such case and pass it the object you want to store like so:

```
<div v-for="ing in recipe.ingredients" :key="ing.id">
    {{ ing.Name }} {{ ing.Quantity }}
    <v-btn class="green darken-1  color mb-5 ml-4 mr-4 pl-50" @click="addToShoppingList(ing)">
        <v-icon class="green darken-1 btn-style">mdi-plus</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
</div>
```

Then in vuex, store it in the state using an action and a mutator:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    shoppingList: []
  },
  getters: {
    getShoppingList(state) { return state.shoppingList }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ITEM_TO_SHOPPING_LIST(state, ingParam) {
        state.shoppingList.push(ingParam);
    }
  }
  ,
  actions: {
    addItemToShoppingList({commit}, ingParam) {
        commit('ADD_ITEM_TO_SHOPPING_LIST', ingParam);
    }
  }
```

And last thing in your methods like so:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        addToShoppingList(ingParam) {
            this.$store.dispatch('addItemToShoppingList', ingParam);
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps ;)